# combinatorics -probability of burned electric bulbs in row

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Given 50 bulbs in a row.In a given time (not maintenance problem) the probability of a burned bulb is 0.1 . Please calculate the probability that  the last 5 bulbs in row are burned. I really doubt about the order "of last". But I think there might be other burned bulbs in that row !!!

Thanks
Jack L.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: It seems to me that Jack has explained exactly where he’s having trouble: he’s not sure whether the states of the first $45$ bulbs affect the result.

Comment: @Brian I'm glad you could make sense out of the last two sentences -- I couldn't. But you're right, this situation wasn't very appropriate for a run-of-the-mill comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to worry about the first $45$ bulbs: the lights are independent of one another. That is, the probability that the $46$-th bulb has burned out is $0.1$ no matter how many of the first $45$ bulbs have burned out. Similarly, the probability that the $47$-th bulb has burned out is $0.1$, and whether it has burned out is independent of whether any of the others have burned out. The answer would be the same if there were only $5$ bulbs, and the question asked for the probability that all $5$ were burned out. That’s just the product of the individual probabilities, so it’s ... what?

Comment: Thanks ! I know the events are independent (it was a studential question - nobody to ask\clearfy). Does this answer fit any sequence of 5 bulbs any where in row ? Is there something tricky about it?

Comment: @Jack: No, nothing tricky: any $5$ bulbs at all would give the same answer. You’re welcome!